# Relacionar módulos Nodejs com Services Angularjs - Electron

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, electron

Olá, Pessoal!
Estou iniciando um estudo em **electron** e nesta aplicação estou usando angularJS, o detalhe é que não intendo muito sobre, e não consigo pensar em uma forma usar o **Node** sem o server estar rodando, em fim gostaria de utilizar os módulos do **node** em um service do **Angular**. 
Vou tentar detalhar melhor com os fontes:

Tenho meu user.model.js:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var UserSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  password: String
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

No meu userService.js:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';    
    var express  = require('express'),
        mongoose = require('mongoose'),
        User     = require('./user.model.js')

    angular.module('app')
        .service('userService', ['$q', UserService]);

    function UserService($q) {
        return {
            create: createUser
            /*getUsers: getUsers,
            getById: getUserById,
            destroy: deleteUser,
            update: updateUser*/
        };

        function createUser(user) {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            User.create(user, function(err, res) {
                if(err) { eferred.reject(err); }
                deferred.resolve(res);
            });
            return deferred.promise;
        }
    }
})();
```

E no controller de minha view (usuarioController.js)

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    angular.module('app')
        .controller('UsuarioController', ['userService', '$q', UsuarioController]);

    function UsuarioController(userService, $q, $mdDialog) {
        var self = this;
        self.User = {};
        self.saveUser = saveUser;

        function saveUser($event) {
            userService.create(self.User).then(function (res) {
                console.log('Salvou' + res);
            });
        }
    }

})();
```

Se alguém souber como posso fazer isso, ficarei muito agradecido!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você tem que considerar a arquitetura proposta pelo electron.

Perceba que o código node, seu service no caso, deve estar executando processo principal ([ipcMain](http://electron.atom.io/docs/api/ipc-main/)). Considere esse código o seu back-end que, por sua vez, não deve depender do Angular.

Por outro lado, o código [Angular](https://angularjs.org/), estará executando no processo renderizador ([ipcRenderer](http://electron.atom.io/docs/api/ipc-renderer/)). Se você tem um serviço Angular aqui, você chamar um outro serviço no back-end.

A comunicação entre eles é através de mensagens/eventos. Você deve enviar uma mensagem as[síncrona] do `renderer` para o `main`. E enviar a resposta as[síncrona] pelo caminho contrário.

Eu implementei, parcialmente, uma aplicação usando [electron](http://electron.atom.io/) e java. O código fonte está no [github](https://github.com/josivan/commareagui). Você pode explorá-la e usar como referência.

Comment: Obrigado @josivan , eu acho que na verdade é melhor eu dar um estudada melho no framework(electron), pq na real eu imaginava que ele apenas realizava o build da aplicação para desktop.

Comment: @LucasHenriquedeAbreu, a ideia é que você faça uma aplicação web rodar no desktop nas plataformas em que o electron está disponível. O electron é um chromiun com node embutido.